# How to run Oracle function which returns more than one value

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

My test function is this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MULTI_VAL
(MYNAME OUT EMP2017.ENAME%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER AS
  MYSAL EMP2017.SAL%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT SAL, ENAME INTO MYSAL, MYNAME FROM EMP2017 ;
  RETURN MYSAL;
END;
/
```

When I run it like

```
variable mynm varchar2(20)

SELECT MULTI_VAL(:mynm) FROM dual;
```

it gives this error

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-06553: PLS-561: character set mismatch on value for parameter 'MYNAME'

Comment: So what is datatype of `EMP2017.MYNAME`?

Comment: Assuming it is `nvarchar2(20)`, what are you database and national character sets? Also I'd expect that query to get `ORA-06572: Function MULTI_VAL has out arguments`, and as the function's query has no filter it will error if there is not exactly one row in the table. What are you really trying to do? Maybe you want to return a ref cursor or a pipelined collection?

Answer (score 2):

The error you get now indicates a datatype mismatch.

However there is a fundamental problem with your code. We cannot use functions which have OUT parameters in SQL. So once you have fixed the datatype issue you will get this error: `ORA-06572: Function MULTI_VAL has out arguments`.

You can run it like this:

```
declare
    n varchar2(20);
    x number;
begin
    x := multi_val(n);
end;
/
```

Generally, functions with OUT parameters are considered bad practice. The syntax allows them, but the usage is hard to understand. It's better to use a procedure with two OUT parameters (because we can only call the program in PL/SQL anyway) or else have the function return a user-defined type.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE EMP2017(ENAME VARCHAR2(10),SAL NUMBER);

INSERT INTO EMP2017 VALUES ('SMITH',5000);
INSERT INTO EMP2017 VALUES ('JOHNS',1000);

COMMIT;

CREATE  TYPE RET_MULT AS OBJECT 
(ENAME     VARCHAR2(10),SAL NUMBER); 

CREATE TYPE T_RET_MULT AS TABLE OF RET_MULT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MULTI_VAL RETURN T_RET_MULT PIPELINED IS 
 MYSAL  RET_MULT;
BEGIN
FOR I IN(SELECT SAL, ENAME FROM EMP2017) LOOP
  MYSAL := RET_MULT(I.ENAME,I.SAL);
  PIPE ROW(MYSAL);
END LOOP ;
RETURN ;
END;

SELECT * FROM TABLE(MULTI_VAL());
```

Comment: Why use pipeline function in this task ? Is it necessary?

Comment: In that solution you can get multi columns and multi rows

Comment: I see it,  but it could be done without  pipelining.

Comment: Yes, possible,This is another solution, which of them is best match it can be used. Table function can also be used as part of select statement and if you execute statement with parallel option, this solution supports that feature

Answer (score 0):

I think this question can be solved without using pipeline functions. Just like this. All pre required data as described @Sedat.Turan except function. Sorry for copy/past.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP2017(ENAME VARCHAR2(10),SAL NUMBER);

INSERT INTO EMP2017 VALUES ('SMITH',5000);
INSERT INTO EMP2017 VALUES ('JOHNS',1000);

COMMIT;

CREATE  TYPE RET_MULT AS OBJECT 
(ENAME     VARCHAR2(10),SAL NUMBER); 

CREATE TYPE T_RET_MULT AS TABLE OF RET_MULT;
    create or replace function MULTI_VAL return T_RET_MULT is
       RET_SET T_RET_MULT;
    begin

       select RET_MULT(ENAME, SAL) bulk collect into RET_SET from EMP2017;

       return RET_SET;
    end;
```

Comment: You're right that Pipelined function is not necessary but both these solutions presume things which aren't in the original question.

Comment: Why do you think so? I think this solution is exactly what question owner wants. According to question I don't think that the correct answer will be the error solving. There no condition on select statement,, and I don't think that there will be only one row at time, so given answers are more suitable for this this question.